# CakePHP 3.x Saving new record but also new associated record

Tags: mysql, cakephp, foreign-keys, cakephp-3.x

So I'm developing a system where a user can create a new account and upload a profile photo. I'm using two models: `User` for the account, `Photo` for the photos.

The `users` table has a foreign key on the field `photoId` that references to `photos.id`. The `photos` table has a `userId` field that has a foreign key referencing `users.id`. So there is a recursive relationship between User and Photo. Reason for this: when a `Photo` is created, we want to be able to see which `User` uploaded the `Photo`. A `User` has one `Photo` as his profile image.

So it's `Photo hasOne User` and `User hasOne Photo`. They are also configured this way in their Table classes.

Now, when a new `User` is saved, we want to also save a new `Photo`. `Photo` needs the id of the newly created `User` in order to save, but the `User` needs the id of the newly created `Photo`.

My question: what is the best method to save this? Should we allow `User.photoId` to be null, so that we can first save the User, then save the Photo, and then update the User with the correct `Photo.id`, or can CakePHP3 do some magic where it does all of this linking back and forth for you?

Data that comes from the form:

```
[
    'username' => 'John Doe',
    'mail' => 'john@example.org',
    'password' => 'whatever',
    'photo' => [
        'name' => 'myImage.jpg',
        'type' => 'image/jpeg',
        'tmp_name' => '/private/var/tmp/phpN3dVmL',
        'error' => (int) 0,
        'size' => (int) 40171
    ]
]
```

Answer (score 1):

**Make Things Simple !**

*Why you need hasOne relations for both table ?*

It looks like you are making simple thing so complected.Let's talk about that:

```
You have two tables users and photos that's fine.
At the moment each user has one photo that's fine as well.
```

Just imagine one day user might have multiple photo, then ?

```
Then still no worries, everything would be good because you have photos table already.
```

So what kind of relations do you actually need here ?

```
Just like mentioned above, user has one photo, That's why relation should be:
user hasOne photo and obviously photo belongsTo user.
```

And you need nothing more than that.

*Just for example*

**Fields on Users table**

```
id
name
email
address
has_photo // eg:if has_photo = 1 user has uploaded photo,such field is not compulsary
password...etc
```

**Fields on Photos table**

```
id
user_id // foreign key of users table
name
size
```

**Relations**

```
// UsersTable.php
  $this->hasOne('Photos', [
      'foreignKey' => 'user_id'
  ]);

 // PhotosTable.php
  $this->belongsTo('Users', [
        'foreignKey' => 'user_id',
        'joinType' => 'INNER'
    ]);
```

Don't be confuse on that photos need user_id..users table never need photo_id.Because users table already associated with photos table. And if A hasOne B then B obviously belongs to A.That's the simple logic.

Don't hesitate to see the documentation ( [Associations](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/associations.html)
) to get more information on relations..This is really important things for database management.

Comment: The point is that `Photos` has multiple relationships with multiple models. I would like to retrieve one `User` with it's one `Photo`. Therefore `User hasOne Photo`. But also `Articles hasMany Photos`, to be able to show Photos with an Article. And `Users` do upload all of these `Photos`, so `Photos hasOne Users`.

Comment: So what is your problem ? If Articles has many photos make that relation too.

Comment: But it's about Photos hasOne Users. The userId in Photos is not filled in automatically, when saving a new User with its new Photo.

Comment: make table as above and bake them using cake bake,everything will be okey.

Answer (score 0):

> or can CakePHP3 do some magic where it does all of this linking back and forth for you?

Yes! As long as your associations are setup correctly Cake will take care of the rest. So the best method is to pass your data array into `newEntity` or `patchEntity` and make sure that all passed fields are accessible in you entity.

[Saving hasOne relationships](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/saving-data.html#saving-hasone-associations)

[Entities and mass assignment](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/entities.html#entities-mass-assignment)

Comment: I'm aware that CakePHP handles hasOne relationships automatically, but that's only when the entity "having" the second entity already exists (because there's an id that the other model can have as its foreign key). But what to do when both entities are new (so don't have an id yet)?

Comment: It should take care of that as well.